# Check If In_Array (in Recursive Associative Array)

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, associative-array

I have an array similar to this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(2) "en"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "English"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(2) "bg"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Bulgarian"
  }
}
```

How do I check if the string Bulgarian is part of the above array, or alternatively if the lang code 'en' is part of the array? It would be great if I didn't have to use foreach to loop through the entire array and compare the string with each element['code'] or element['name'].

Comment: What have you tried , have you tried any code ? if so please post it in your question, so you can be helped.

Comment: In some form or another you'll always need a loop. Even `in_array` loops internally.

Comment: _" It would be great if I didn't have to use foreach to loop through the entire array and compare the string with each element"_ - then how would you find what you're looking for?

Comment: @deceze, true. But that doesn't mean I'd advocate custom `foreach` loops over `in_array()` (where applicable of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// $type could be code or name
function check_in_array($arr, $value, $type = "code") {
  return count(array_filter($arr, function($var) use ($type, $value) {
    return $var[$type] === $value;
  })) !== 0;
}
```

Comment: This code looks like throwing undefined variable warnings all over the place. I wonder how TS got this to work. Also you should do an early exit if found. There is no need to count higher than one.

Comment: Another var was missing, still wondering about early exit, I'd say `foreach` ain't bad here.

Comment: @hakre Yep, `foreach` is better here, just show the way other than it

Comment: My experience is this works in `PHP 5.3.1` but not in `5.2.17`

Answer (score 1):

I know my code used foreach but it is easy to understand and use.

```
$language=array();
$language[0]['code']='en';
$language[0]['name']='English';
$language[1]['code']='bg';
$language[1]['name']='Bulgaria';

var_dump(my_in_array('Bulgaria', $language));

function my_in_array($search, $array) {
    $in_keys = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(in_array($search, $value)){
            $in_keys[]=$key;
        }
    }
    if(count($in_keys) > 0){
        return $in_keys;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for recursive search

```
function in_arrayr($needle, $haystack) {
        foreach ($haystack as $v) {
                if ($needle == $v) return true;
                elseif (is_array($v)) return in_array($needle, $v);
        }
        return false;
}
```

Or you can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on your array and search occurence of substring :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so I made this function, it's like in_array, but it can search in array in the array recursively. I think it's correct but I didn't test in a lot of case. (sorry for my english I'm french)

```
function in_arrayr($needle, $haystack) {
if(is_array($haystack)){
    foreach($haystack as $elem){
        $a = in_arrayr($needle,$elem)||$a;
    }
}
else{
    $a = (($needle == $haystack)? true: false);
}
    return $a;
}
```