# in_array to check if it contains a date in mm/dd/yyy format

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have a dynamic array `$v` whose contents change according to a form being submitted. Some forms might have a date field and others may not. For all forms I'm using the same array `$v` to store values in a `key=>value` pair and then insert it into the table. So sometimes the array may look like

```
$v = array('patron_name'=>'some value',
           'place' => 'again some value',
           'pin' => 'blah blah')
```

and at other times it may look like

```
$v = array('joomla'=>'some value again',
           'date_applied' => '23/04/2012',
          )
```

As seen above, the contents vary from form to form. What I'm looking for is to first check if `$v` contains a value in the form of `dd/mm/yyy` and if it does, change it to `yyyy-mm-dd` format to insert into table. I can handle the conversion part, but I'm stuck at determining if `$v` contains a date or not.

So basically I'm intending to proceed in this way:

```
if(in_array('date in dd/mm/yyyy format', $v))
{
  // change it to yyyy-mm-dd
}
// and then insert into table
$flag = insert($tablename, $v);
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `in_array`, use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Pass the array to it and match for the date format pattern. If the pattern matches, replace it with the callback.

Example ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/54Bme4)):

```
$v = array(
    'joomla'=>'some value again',
    'date_applied' => '23/04/2012',
);

$result = preg_replace_callback('#^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$#', function($match) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $match[0])->format('Y-m-d');
}, $v);

print_r($result);
```

On a sidenote, since Y-m-d contains the same values as d/m/Y, you don't strictly need to use a callback but can just use `preg_replace` ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hmVYxg)):

```
$result = preg_replace('#^(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})$#', '$3-$2-$1', $v);
```

Using a callback would allow you to use an arbitrary date format though.

Comment: This sounds good. However, preg_match is a bit of a sore subject for me. I'll google and see if I get a preg_match to match 'dd/mm/yyyy' and if everything works fine, will accept your answer

Comment: Perfect +1 and accepted. Btw, any idea why when I use the above code in DW CS5, I get syntax errors highlighted near those lines?

Comment: Nvm, I'm using just the preg_replace as suggested

Comment: @aspirin sorry, I have no clue about DW. I could imagine it doesn't have closure support and thus cannot recognize the callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk()` for that, coupled with `preg_match()`:

```
function handle_dates(&$v)
{
    if (preg_match('#^(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})$#', $v, $matches)) {
        $v = sprintf("%02d-%02d-%02d", $matches[3], $matches[2], $matches[1]);
    }
}

array_walk($v, 'handle_dates');
```

Or:

```
function replace_dates($v)
{
    return preg_replace('#^(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})$#', '\3-\2-\1', $v);
}

$v = array_map('replace_dates', $v);
```

Comment: I'm getting syntax error on the lines where I'm using `$v = array_map(function($v) {
    return preg_replace('#^(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})$#', '\3-\2-\1', $v);
}, $v);`

Comment: @asprin That syntax is introduced in 5.3; check again pls.

Comment: Thanks Jack for your effort. But I got what I was looking for. +1 btw

Comment: @asprin Yeah, `preg_replace()` applied on the array is nicer in a way; it's less memory friendly though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

in_array doesn't take an associative array, there are numerous examples on how to make this work though: [Check If In_Array (in Recursive Associative Array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009875/check-if-in-array-in-recursive-associative-array) (but defintly look for a better one ;))

as for checking if there's a date you can do multiple things.

If you know the date will always be in a dd/mm/yyyy format you can use a regular expression for this (google should give enough results), use preg_match to check if the value contains a string in the given format, if so format it.

If the format can be changed (e.g. if its human input, people tend to use / or - depending on language specifics, simply testing if strtotime(); returns false or not can be enough.

An example regular expression 'untested'

```
  if (preg_match('/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/', $date) {
    // date found
  }
```

Comment: This is close enough to what I want, but I can't use the `$date` variable as to store the date inside `$date`, I will have to use something like `$date = $v['applied_date']` but the array keys of `$v` are not always the same, i.e., it can be anything for a date value

Comment: A very crude example: foreach ($array as $k => $v) { if (preg_match($regexp, $v) { // date found } } but below are multiple, better, example of how to do this loop

Comment: Thanks Tjirp for your effort. But I got what I was looking for. +1 btw

Answer (score 0):

What about using [array_search](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php) to determine if your array contains the string in that format? And getting the key, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it easily as

```
if($v['date_applied']!="")
{
$date=date_create($v['date_applied']);
$fdate=date_format($date,'Y-m-d');
}
```

then your code to insert

Comment: I can't hardcode `$v['date_applied']` as it can also be `$v[key_value_can_anything]`.